# Format of the "classifier" in the dependency:properties goal

Tags: java, maven, maven-dependency-plugin

The [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/properties-mojo.html) about `dependency:properties` goal of the Maven dependency plugin states, that:

> Goal that sets a property pointing to the artifact file for each
>   project dependency. For each dependency (direct and transitive) a
>   project property will be set which follows the
>   groupId:artifactId:type:[classifier] form and contains the path to the
>   resolved artifact.

But I can not find the description of what is `classifier`.

In my build logs I see that it uses the snapshot version plus build timestamp, like this:

`foo.group.id:foo.artifact.id:jar:0.1.2-20180213.101423-2`

My question: where this format is configured?

Comment: This part `-20180212.101423-2` is the `0.1.2-SNAPSHOT` part which is replaced by a time stamp and buildnumber for the transport to your repository manager....

Comment: Asking my question again: this format, is it default? Where it is configured?